# Moving through panes in AUI managed frame

Tags: python, wxpython

My `wx.Frame` derived class is managed by `AuiManager`. I have several panes in this frame (all are derived from `wx.Panel` and all have `wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL` flag set). Pressing `TAB` key on the keyboard moves focus inside every pane correctly. The problem is, I don't know how to (or even if it is possible) move focus to the next pane. Any ideas about this?

P.S. I've tried googling and reading through `wxPython` docs, but couldn't find any clue.

Comment: please post a minimum working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to be as helpful as I can, given the little information you provided. To shift the focus to another Panel use that [Panel's SetFocus() function](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Panel.html#wx.Panel.SetFocus). (See function description in the link)

Your question also seems to imply that you are interested in the key bindings of focus events. To manage the key bindings to focus events in wxpython, please checkout [wx.NavigationKeyEvent](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.NavigationKeyEvent.html). This will allow you to get and set the directions and events resulting from your navigation key inputs.

Last, have you tried pressing the [page down] key for switching panes?

Comment: `wx.EVT_NAVIGATION_KEY` binding was way to go. I used binding of this event to check which panel has focus, and implemented logic to which panel focus should be switched. There was some work here, because You must cover all cases (disabled fields, panels hidden...), but your answer was pointing at the right direction. Thanks.